# Cannot connect DBeaver SQL Server to Rider, although DBeaver PhpMyAdmin MySQL connection works on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, jetbrains-ide

First of all, I work on UBUNTU, so please do not give me Windows solutions.
I want to connect my SQL Server (which is configured in DBeaver) to Rider (JetBrains).

Through DBeaver, I managed to establish a MySQL connection to PhpMyAdmin, via port 3306; this means that I can modify my PhpMyAdmin MySQL database x from SQL Server (DBeaver). However, when I intend to add a new Microsoft SQL SERVER connection in Rider (writing the correct username, password, database, server host and port) and test the connection, the classic error pops up:

> [08S01] The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 3306 has failed. Error: "The driver received an unexpected pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2005 or later.". ClientConnectionId:69c13d8a-1f4f-4faf-ba64-b3a9b2ebcd13.

Note that if I connect to Rider via MySQL, everything works. The problem I face is SQL Server.

**UPDATE:**
It does not work on port 1433 either

[image: descriptive image Rider]

**UPDATE:**
DBeaver MySQL connection

[image]

Comment: But you said MySQL is running on port 3306, not SQL Server.  SQL Server runs on port 1433 by default.

Comment: it does not work with 1433 port either

Comment: SQL Server may not be listening on TCP ports. You may have connected via pipe/socket or another connection mechanics and not TCP... try showing your DBeaver connection details here (as a screenshot)

Comment: I updated my question with the image

Comment: How did you install SQL Server?

Comment: Well... that 2nd screenshot is for **MySQL**. You can add that MySQL Database to Rider using the same details and that should work. **I see nothing for **SQL Server** (that is the subject here). If you can connect to SQL Server with another tool (DBeaver?) then post a setting (screenshot) of that. How do you connect to your SQL Server elsewhere (code etc)?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sudo apt install mysql-server

Comment: @LazyOne ok, the my problem is this: I want to complete this tutorial, so that I can use Entity Framework: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1mA7EU5aPw. BUT, connecting Rider to MySQL DOES NOT display the migration option in my project. As shown in the tutorial, I have to connect to MySQL SERVER; otherwise it won't work

Comment: `sudo apt install mysql-server` that doesn't install Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: MySQL Server and Microsoft SQL Server are 2 different things. You have MySQL already, use it.

Comment: thank you everyone for answers!